# Append a list of object to an array of object

Tags: javascript

I want to append a list of object as

```
listObj = {1:{id:1,name:"fgh"}, 2:{id:2, name:ghj}}
```

to an array

```
arrayObj = {child:[
0:{id:3,name:fghj}
1:{id:9, name:cvbn}
]}
```

So final expected arrayObj should be

```
 arrayObj = {child:[
    0:{id:3,name:fghj}
    1:{id:9, name:cvbn}
     2:{id:1,name:"fgh"}
     3:{id:2, name:ghj}
    ]}
```

I have tried append but it is not giving expected result

Comment: Have you tried .push() to insert elements into array

Comment: wrong syntax.. not a valid arrayObj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the values with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the source object and push the items to the target array with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var listObj = { 1: { id: 1, name: 'fgh' }, 2: { id: 2, name: 'ghj' } },
    arrayObj = { child: [{ id: 3, name: 'fghj' }, { id: 9, name: 'cvbn' }] };

arrayObj.child.push(...Object.values(listObj));

console.log(arrayObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get each property which are related to the current object via `for in` loop, check if those are in the current object and push them into `arrayObj.child` array.

```js
var listObj = { 1: {id:1, name:"fgh"}, 2: {id:2, name:"ghj"}}

var arrayObj = {child:[
    {id:3,name:"fghj"},
    {id:9, name:"cvbn"}
]};

for(var prop in listObj){
   if(listObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      arrayObj.child.push(listObj[prop]);
   }
}

console.log(arrayObj.child);
```

Or as @Nina suggests, via `Object.values()`. Be attentive that here we use also `... spread` operator.

```js
var listObj = { 1: {id:1, name:"fgh"}, 2: {id:2, name:"ghj"}}

var arrayObj = {child:[
    {id:3,name:"fghj"},
    {id:9, name:"cvbn"}
]};

arrayObj.child.push(...Object.values(listObj));

console.log(arrayObj.child);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into an array using

```
Object.keys(listObj).map(function (key) { return listObj[key]; });
```

```js
let listObj = {1:{id:1,name:"fgh"}, 2:{id:2, name:'ghj'}};
// converts listObj into an array
var arr = Object.keys(listObj).map(function (key) { return listObj[key]; });
//console.log(arr);

arrayObj = {child:[
{id:3,name:'fghj'},
{id:9, name:'cvbn'}
]}
//just concat into the array now
arrayObj.child = arrayObj.child.concat(arr);

console.log(arrayObj);
```